# GRPC for android: Import different protoc file

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I'm using GRPC framework for my project. For example here is my sample directory structure for storing protoc file:

```
main
  proto
    model
      user.proto
    include
      base.proto
```

I want to include base.proto into user.proto but I don't know how. I have tried some way to include that such as:

```
import "include/base.proto"
import "../include/base.proto".
```

But it doesn't work. I always receive error like:

```
import "include/base.proto" was not found or had errors.
```

Please help me figure out this problem.

Comment: There was a similar-sounding issue reported for some users with Android: https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/107. The issue is closed and I am unable to reproduce the reported error, but if Eric Anderson's answer below doesn't work for you, please follow up on the Github issue and provide your proto definitions and what version of the protobuf plugin and compiler you are using. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way should be:

```
import "include/base.proto";
```

gRPC uses that type of path in [multiple](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.4.0/testing-proto/src/main/proto/io/grpc/testing/integration/test.proto#L34) [tests](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.4.0/services/src/test/proto/io/grpc/reflection/testing/reflection_test.proto#L35).